# Conversion from long to BitSet and left shift operations

Tags: java

I try to convert the following code from long to BitSet:

```
private static void createOptions(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<long[]> moves) {
    moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit1), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3),
            (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
    moves.add(new long[]{(1L << bit3), (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit1),
            (1L << bit1) | (1L << bit2) | (1L << bit3)});
}

private static void createOptions(int bit1, int bit2, int bit3, ArrayList<BitSet[]> moves) {
    // How can I do a bitwise left-shift with BitSet?
}
```

But there seem to be no bitwise left-shift operation in Java BitSet.
What can I do?

Comment: Don't you just need `set(bit1)`, `set(bit2)`, `set(bit3)`?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm starting with bitwise operations and it's still not completely clear to me yet. I will take a look and update if it's really just setting bits

Comment: `BitSet` is a kind of `Set<Integer>` every integer represented as bit 1 in a contiguout bit array. Not suited for bit shifting, as one would first need to unpack in a `long[]` and cumbersomely do it all yourself. Use `long` or `long[]`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, How can I use set(bit) in the same line of creating a new BitSet? i.e `moves.add(new BitSet[]{(set(bit1)),` but it needs a specific name to use the `set` method.

@JoopEggen, I can't I need to use sets of bits longer than 64 (representing different game boards).

Comment: Understood a but late, as you were converting from long to bitset. `long[]` then.

Comment: @JoopEggen You mean array of longs? so if the board is 70 cells, create 2 long arrays?

Comment: `long[] bits = new long[2];`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please help me determine if it's the right solution? The code i'm trying to convert to fit more than 64 cell boards is this: https://blackflux.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/peg-solitaire-brute-force/
And I'm not sure what would be better - converting everything to `BitSet`, or it would be better to do as you said in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The following would use `long[2]`.

```
class Bits128 {
    long[] bits = new long[2];

    void shift(int n) {
        n %= 64;
        if (n > 0) {
            bits[1] <<= n;
            bits[1] |= bits[0] >> (64 - n);
            bits[0] <<= n;
        }
        if (n < 0) ...
    }

    boolean isSet(int i) {
       bits[i/64] & (1L << (i % 64)) != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to implement this to fit the code in the link I posted in the comment. I will update if I manage to understand this. Right now I am having hard time